# 2 different Online-Shops in one Magento with same stock management

Tags: magento2, multistore

Is it possible to have 2 complete different shops (different product page but same products)? The on stock management should be same for both shops.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Actually this is one of Magento's strongest features. Your requirements are described very limited, but you should be looking into Magento's *storeviews*, *stores* and *websites*.

Start reading here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

You can have your shops on different domains, you can have the shops on the same domain but in different folders or subdomains. You can share products and other entities (customers, catalog, etc.) over different shops. There are many possibilities.